# Tikz plots incorrectly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

What am I doing wrong? Here is a MWE, below the plots as they should look like.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-3:4]
\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-2.9,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$t$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {};
 
\draw[samples=400] plot (\x,{3*sin(\x) + 0.3*(\x)^2}) node[right] {};

\draw plot[color=blue,thick] (\x,{3-0.03*exp(-(\x))+sin(3*(\x))*1/(6*(\x))}) node[right] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: Though, what I get is:

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that TikZ takes the angles in degrees?

Comment: Oh sh..oosh! I am not! Thank you! Should I delete the question in shame or leave it?

Comment: You can change this writing `sin(deg(\x))` for example.

Comment: I just found `sin(\x r)` works as conversion to radians. Thanks for you hint!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved with the comments.

Comment: @Sebastiano Absolutely. I just didnt know how or if I can do this myself. The comment solved the question.